# How to solve the UnicodeDecodeError when using stanford parser API in NLTK for python?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, nltk, stanford-nlp

I want to use stanford parser using Python, I use Windows 7, I've installed Python 2.7 and nltk 3.0 and I downloaded the stanford parser from the official site.

I got the javahome environment problem which I solved, then I got this error message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

and I can't find a solution for this problem.

I used the next code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from nltk.parse import stanford

parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\nlp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz')

sent = 'my name is zim'
parser.parse(sent)
```

I've looked in stack overflow for a solution but I didn't find one.

Comment: simple solution, use `python3` =)

Comment: Are you sure your code runs using `\n` in your path?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365626/how-to-output-nltk-chunks-to-file/28381060#28381060

Comment: Guys i'm so gratful for your help, i did what you suggested @alvas (it was hard to do what the others suggested xd but still thank you guys for your time :D), i downloaded python 3.3.3 and nltk 3.0.2. Now i'm getting this error: "raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed :...". it seems like it is a Java command failed error. I've no idea what is this error, it is killing me :p. plz help me to make stanford parser work, i REALLY need it for my project.

Comment: have you installed JRE?

Comment: Yes, and i'm using jdk1.8.0_20 and jre1.8.0_20, i tried to add there paths to the environment variable (the Path variable), but still doesn't work.             Note that i use another variable (JAVAHOME varibale) which contain the path of the jdk and not the jre. My jdk and jre are installed in C:\Program Files\Java. any suggestions @alvas ?. so sorry for wasting your time .

Comment: A comprehensive answer came in on the same day, but you do not appear to have voted on it, accepted it or replied to it. May I ask why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was the problem that caused the error that I've encountered

> raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd)) OSError: Java command failed :...

This error is due to the bad interpretation of the address in the following instruction :

```
parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\nlp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz').
```

Python or Java interpreted the `...\nlp\..` as `\n lp\...`, so as a result, it couldn't find the path.

I've tried a simple solution, I've renamed the folder nlp. And it worked!

Answer (score 2):

If the `os.environ` or `export` paths are set properly as described in this: [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk), then it should be an issue of

- specifying the encoding in the NLTK API **AND**
- the encoding of your input string

So the solution would be:

- update NLTK to the latest stable version i.e. `sudo pip install -U nltk`
- use `python3`!!!! or specify the encoding for your string

If you're somehow unable to update your python or NLTK, then:

- specify the encoding when using Stanford API in NLTK (because of https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/877)
- specify the encoding for your string (see [How to output NLTK chunks to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365626/how-to-output-nltk-chunks-to-file/28381060#28381060))

It is **STRONGLY** recommended that you use `python3` especially when handling text inputs.

If all else fails, and you only have the old version of NLTK and you must somehow use py2.7, then:

```
import six
from nltk.parse import stanford

path_to_model = "C:\Program Files (x86)\stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30\edu\stanford\nlp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz"

parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path=path_to_model, encoding='utf8')

sent = six.text_type('my name is zim')
parser.parse(sent)
```

See `six` docs @ http://pythonhosted.org//six/#six.text_type

Answer (score 1):

`0xe9` isn't a valid ASCII byte, so your `englishPCFG.ser.gz` must not be ASCII encoded. You'll need to figure out what encoding it's using (probably UTF-8) and tell `StanfordParser()` about it with the `encoding` keyword argument.

Comment: that's only part of the problem, the default encoding for NLTK3.0's stanford API is `ascii` it has been changed to 'utf8' in the latest version, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/877. The other part is how the OP read the string, using python3 and the latest stable version of NLTK resolves the issue.